# Which characters appear in the most Star Trek episodes and movies?

Tags: star-trek

Worf and Miles O'Brien appeared in more Star Trek TV shows and movies than any other characters.

**After them, which characters appeared in the most episodes and movies?**

Comment: Spock, presumably. He's in every episode of TOS, all the TOS films, several TNG episodes, all the new films and a bunch of that Discovery nonsense.

Comment: Picard, Troi, and Riker have to be up there. Probably in that specific order, relative to each other. Data too, I think.

Comment: I doubt that Spock is even in the top 10. TNG, DS9 and VOY all ran for 7 seasons.  TOS ran for 3. Harry Kim, for example,  is credited in 168 episodes. Spock in  79 episodes of TOS, 22 episodes of TAS, 7 movies, and a handful of others.  Maybe 115-ish altogether.

Comment: Presumably, Mr. Anonymous redshirt :-)

Answer (score 7):

Very likely next would be Picard himself

He appears on:

- 176 episodes of TNG
- 10 episodes of Picard
- 1 episode of DS9
- 4 Star Trek movies

That makes for 191 appearances.

After him we have Diana Troi with 185

- 176 appearances on TNG
- 3 appearances on Voyager
- 4 movies
- 1 episode of Picard
- 1 episode of Star Trek Enterprise

After her I think Commander Riker with 184:

- 176 appearances on TNG
- 1 appearance on Voyager
- 1 appearance on DS9
- 4 movies
- 1 episode of Picard
- 1 episode of Star Trek Enterprise

Note Data and Dr Soong are different characters and that makes it difficult to judge Data appearances as a character but I'd say he's the next likely candidate although that's disputed.

Comment: Troi did appear in a few of the later episodes of _Voyager_ (the ones with Lt. Barclay in them). She and Riker were also in the series finale of _Enterprise_, but Riker was in several more episodes of _TNG_ than she was, so he has more appearances overall, contrary to my previous comment beneath the question.

Comment: @LogicDictates you are right, she appears on 3 episodes in Voyager

Comment: Troi and Riker have also appeared in Lower Decks and may do so again.  Based on your numbers that wouldn't catch them up to Picard though, not yet.

Comment: @EricNolan Riker on 3 episodes so far and Troi in 1 episode. However canonicity of Lower Decks is ... controversial and I was honestly hinking on the tv shows only

Answer (score 5):

**The computer, voiced by [Majel Barrett/Roddenberry](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Computer_voice).**

*Whilst I've not been able to track down a precise number, she's obviously way ahead of the closest competition.*

Star Trek the original series season 1,episode 3 ([Mudd's Women](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Mudd%27s_Women_(episode))) onward.

The Next Generation (most episodes).

Deep Space 9, voice of computer in The Defiant.

A single episode of Enterprise.

Voyager, most episodes.

Star Trek Generations, Star Trek: First Contact, Star Trek Insurrection, Star Trek: Nemesis.

Her voiceover for J.J. Abrams reboot, Star trek was completed 8 days before her death.

Also various Star Trek Games, animations and associated media (too many to track-down).

Since before her death, Majel spent considerable time [recording words phonetically](https://fantasticfacts.net/3443/), this has allowed Star Trek Discovery to incorporate her voice occasionally and will allow the Roddenberry legacy to still have this continuity for as long as it exists.

Comment: Interesting answer, but is the ship's computer a character?

Comment: Is Data? The computer tried to seduce Kirk once, something Data didn't. I guess it depends on your definition. @RichS

Comment: I agree about the sentience thing, the same character? Hmm, existential question for the philosophers to chew over perhaps. Again, your definition holds sway. I'd say "character" applies to anything played by an actor or actress (or puppeteer etc.), but then that's my background so I'm biassed. @RichS I'd also say, if they're credited then it counts, but many performers go unaccredited (vis a vis Eddie Murphy TNG).

Comment: Data is sentient. The computer is not, and therefore not a character. Also, would you claim that the ship's computer is the **same** character in every ship in every series?

Comment: It has the same name (computer) and is played by the same performer with the same voice and speech pattern, also performs the same function each time without any deviation (with the exception of that one episode of TOS after the refit when it went weird). I'd say if it's a character then it's the same each time. If you're not defining it as a character then it's moot whether it's the same or not.

Comment: It seems 'she' outdoes Worf / Miles O'Brien, which were mentioned in the question.

Comment: I would disagree that the computer is the same character each time. Computers of the same type would be installed in other starships so it can't be in several different places simultaneously. Also, the speech pattern of the 1701 computer was very stilted and in a monotone; the one aboard 1701-D sounded much more natural.

Comment: Yes, this is a false answer.   Even if we accept that the computer's voices is a character (dubious), the voice of different computers definitely is not the same character.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. it does make sense that Data didn't try to seduce Kirk. But your point stands. :D

Comment: I would argue that each instantiation of the computer is unique, thus you can only count the Enterprise-D, Voyager, DS9 usages as seperate and distinct. However, in the TNG episode 'Emergence' it is stated quite clearly that the computer became "a self-determining intelligence" that then reproduced

Comment: @ARogueAnt.: "It has the same name (computer)" - err ... wasn't it more that it had *no* name, and therefore was exclusively addressed with its function (similar to "Captain" or (to cite another example of a character without a name) "Doctor")? I'd argue that claiming the computers were the same character because they had the same "name" ("Computer") would also make Kirk, Picard, Sisko after S3, Janeway, and Archer the same character, because they were addressed by the same "name" ("Captain").

Comment: "Majel spent considerable time recording words phonetically" - it should be noted that the article mentions "[her] voice" and "phonemes". rather than "words". It is not clear from that text that she recorded actual "words" (rather than samples from which words can be synthesized).

Comment: I think this would be a valid answer if it were asking which actors, but since it is 'Which characters', I don't think it works; MJR voiced a lot of characters, including Lwaxana Troi in TNG, #1 in the Star Trek Pilot, then Nurse Chapel in the series, and so on.  AND the computer in many branches.. but not the same character.

Comment: If we're calling the computer a "character" then there is no reason it would be the same character across the different ships. It's like saying your computer is the same "character" as my computer just because we both run Windows (assuming you do) and both call our computers computers. It's possible (and even probable) that not only has each computer got different hardware but running different software given that Defiant, Enterprise and Voyager are all completely different classes of ships! They just happen to have the same voice interface. (Majel)

Comment: This answer is like saying IPads, iPhone, MacBook Pros, and Apple TVS are all the same character because they all have the same Siri voice.

Comment: Interestingly though, it's had more total up-votes than the leading answer, (10 up, 6 down at this time) apparently not everyone agrees. @RichS